# SAR statistics on CPU usage

Tags: ubuntu, cpu-usage, sar

i have Ubuntu server with 2 processors.
`top` command show that mysql eats up to 195%.
`sar` shows the following:

```
08:30:59 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
08:31:00 AM     all     75.12      0.00      0.00      0.00     22.89      1.99
```

I the following questions:

1. Could please someone explain what does `%steal` means?

I found the following description in manual, but can hardly understand what does it means:

```
%steal 
Percentage of time spent in involuntary wait by the virtual CPU or CPUs while the hypervisor was servicing another virtual processor.
```

2. CPU usage of process computed as "%user" + "%steal"?

I understand that the following questions are general and answers can depends on many factors but i need just some guidelines: what to do, what to find out and so on. Any docs, links are appreciated ( I didn't find anything very useful. Just general information)

3. Is "%steal" value is fine?
4. What is the edge value for CPU usage when I should worry about it?

ps. not Linux DBA just dev.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering one of your question - `Could please someone explain what does %steal means?`

> *steal time* is a metric that only has meaning in a virtualized computing environment. It represents the amount of CPU that is taken
>   away from a virtual machine to serve other purposes.

BTW, are you running your Ubuntu server in a cloud/VMWare environment?

You may also find [this presentation](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/linux390/perf/CPU_time_accounting.pdf) from IBM helpful, which explains what steal time is and why it exists.